# How to configure SRV records on Ubuntu (running on Amazon EC2)?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm running the Bitnami [TomcatStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/tomcatstack) _ which is based on Ubuntu 10.04 _ on Amazon EC2.

I have installed an Openfire server on top of it for handling XMPP, and in order to be able to chat with Google Talk clients, I have to define several SRV entries in the form:

```
_xmpp-server._tcp.YOURDOMAIN.COM. IN SRV 5 0 5269 xmpp-server.l.google.
```

Currently, I'm not trying to use any custom domain name. That is, instead of YOURDOMAIN.COM, I'm planning to put the default public DNS of my EC2 instance, in the form:

```
ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I think that "everything is in place", as I'm able to telnet on port 5269, from my Mac to the EC2 machine.

I guess the solution involves working with the "bind" command, but I could not find any tutorial adapted to my particular configuration, so thanks in advance for any tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration has little to do with what you want to do (assuming you really have to create the SRV records). Setting any records on a host name requires that you can access and manage your zone - i.e. your domain. Which means, you need to use a custom domain name and have management rights over it. As long as your server lives in amazonaws.com there is in all likelyhood no way you can change its RRS (short for Resource RecordS).

"BIND" - on the other hand - is the "Berkeley Internet Domain Name Server" which you need to be concerned about only if you intend to run your own name server - which is not required for what you want to do. (BTW BIND is the name of the suite, which contains no 'bind' command: the suite's main item is called 'named')

Comment: Thanks. I ended up setting a domain name via Godaddy and setting up everything using their Zone File Editor: modified tha A record to point to my Elastic-IP and followed this great tutorial to setup the SRV part: http://www.olark.com/gtalk/check_srv#tutorial